# Convert the html to pdf with css styling, bootstrap styling and change element on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to convert a timetable to pdf with css styling. However, I have found very few ways to convert the html to pdf with css styling that work how I would like it to. So what I am trying to do is convert this part of html to pdf. I used to link to a different style sheet and convert it to pdf. However, it shrinks the timetable and cannot show all the timeslots. In addition, the original print function that I used from other people doesn't show the buttons in the timetable when it is printed.

```
<div id="content">

<div id="tableSpace">

    <!-- Date scroll bar fixed to top of schedule -->
    <div id="dateScroll">

    </div>

    <div id="timetable">
    <!-- Times column -->
        <div class="dayColumn" id="timeColumn">
            <div class="time">7:30 - 8:30 AM</div>
            <div class="time">8:30 - 9:30 AM</div>
            <div class="time">9:30 - 10:30 AM</div>
            <div class="time">10:30 - 11:30 AM</div>
            <div class="time">11:30 - 12:30 PM</div>
            <div class="time">12:30 - 1:30 PM</div>
            <div class="time">1:30 - 2:30 PM</div>
            <div class="time">2:30 - 3:30 PM</div>
            <div class="time">3:30 - 4:30 PM</div>
            <div class="time">4:30 - 5:30 PM</div>
            <div class="time">5:30 - 6:30 PM</div>
            <div class="time">6:30 - 7:30 PM</div>
            <div class="time">7:30 - 8:30 PM</div>
            <div class="time">8:30 - 9:30 PM</div>
            <div class="time">9:30 - 10:30 PM</div>
            <div class="time">10:30 - 11:30 PM</div>
            <div class="time">11:30 - 12:30 AM</div>
        </div>

        <!-- Monday -->
        <div class="dayColumn" id="mondayFunday">

        </div>

        <!-- Tuesday -->
        <div class="dayColumn" id="tuesdayFunday">

        </div>

        <!-- Wednesday -->
        <div class="dayColumn" id="wednesdayFunday">

        </div>

        <!-- Thursday -->
        <div class="dayColumn" id="thursdayFunday">

        </div>

        <!-- Friday -->
        <div class="dayColumn" id="fridayFunday">

        </div>

        <!-- Saturday -->
        <div class="dayColumn">
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Sunday -->
        <div class="dayColumn">
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
            <div class="timeSlot"></div>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

The main goal of this website is to let someone export the timetable to pdf after they use the the buttons in the eventlist to modify their timetables. I am expected to give a button as a function to export the timetable to pdf. Here is the link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/zeyingzhou/pen/drJLKj

Expect result of the pdf:

[image: Expect result of the pdf]

Comment: How are you actually generating the PDF?

Comment: Generally you'll need to have a web server running, if so I suggest looking at wkhtmltopdf, which allows you to convert a html document to a pdf file (https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)

Comment: The method that I used is just some javascript codes copied from others. It works but it does not satisfy my requirements...